# How do I make state properties that have boolean values appear on the screen (react forms)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a travel form in react js. one of the inputs from the user are checkboxes that needs the user to check the boxes according to their dietary restriction (ie Vegan,Kosher,Lactose free). How do I make  this properties display on the screen when their respective boxes are checked. I'm having a tough time doing this since react does not display properties in state with boolean values.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      age: "",
      gender: "",
      destination: "",
      isVegan: false,
      isKosher: false,
      isLactoseFree: false
      
       }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
 
  handleChange(event){
   const {name, value, type, checked}= event.target
   type === "checkbox" ? 
   this.setState({[name]:checked}) : 
   this.setState({[name]:value})
   
 }

  
  render(){
    return(
       <main>
      <form> 
       
        <input
          value = {this.state.firstName}
          type= "text" 
          name="firstName"  
          placeholder= "First Name"                   
          onChange= {this.handleChange}/> 
     
     <input 
        value = {this.state.lastName}
        type= "text" 
        name="lastName"  
        placeholder= "Last Name" 
        onChange= {this.handleChange}
     />
     <br/>
        
     <input 
       value = {this.state.age}
       type= "number"
       name = "age"
       placeholder = "Age"
       onChange = {this.handleChange}
      />   
      <br />
        <label>
          
          <input
          value= "Male"
          name = "gender"
          type = "radio"
          checked = {this.state.gender === "Male"}
          onChange ={this.handleChange}
          
          />Male
           
          
          </label>
       <br />
        <label>
        <input
          value= "Female"
          name = "gender"
          type = "radio"
          checked = {this.state.gender === "Female"}
          onChange ={this.handleChange}
          
          />Female
        </label>
        
        <br />
        
        <select
          value = {this.state.destination}
          name = "destination"
          onChange = {this.handleChange}
          
          > 
          <option value = "">-- Please choose a destination --</option>
          <option value = "germany">Germany </option>
          <option value = "italy"> Italy</option>
          <option value = "spain"> Spain </option>
          <option value = "norway"> Norway </option>
        
         </select>
        <br />
        <label> 
          <input 
            type = "checkbox"
            name = "isVegan"
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            checked = {this.state.isVegan}
           /> Vegan
         </label>
        
        <br />
        
         <label> 
          <input 
            type = "checkbox"
            name = "isKosher"
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            checked = {this.state.isKosher}
           /> Kosher
         </label>
        
        <br />
        
         <label> 
          <input 
            type = "checkbox"
            name = "isLactoseFree"
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            checked = {this.state.isLactoseFree}
           /> Lactose free
         </label>
        <br />
        <button> Submit </button>
      </form>
    <hr/>
        
        <h1> Passenger's Info </h1>
        <p>  Name : {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName} </p>
        <p>  Age : {this.state.age} </p>
        <p>  Gender : {this.state.gender} </p>
        <p>  Travel Destination : {this.state.destination} </p>
        <p> Dietary Restrictions : </p>
        
    </main>
    
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try <p>Is vegan: {String(this.state.booleanProperty)} </p>

Comment: Or {this.state.booleanPropery ? "yes" : "no"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering, like

```
{this.state.isVegan ? "Yes" : "No"}
```

or any other form of converting boolean values to renderable content, something like the following that filters restriction data by what is enabled in state and displays the text as a comma separated list.

```
const dietaryRestrictions = [
  {
    id: 'isVegan',
    text: 'Vegan',
  },
  {
    id: 'isKosher',
    text: 'Kosher',
  },
  {
    id: 'isLactoseFree',
    text: 'Lactose Free',
  },
];

...

<p>
  Dietary Restrictions:{" "}
  {dietaryRestrictions
    .filter(({ id }) => this.state[id])
    .map(({ text }) => text)
    .join(", ")}
</p>
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-make-state-properties-that-have-boolean-values-appear-on-the-screen-re]

Comment: thanks for your answert. but where do I put the dietaryRestrictions object. I added it to the constructor but the code doesnt work.I dont know if the code or am not getting it right.

Comment: @Collins_obi It can be defined anywhere so long as it is in scope where you want to use it, i.e. in my sandbox it is used in the render function. Since it seems like it won't be updated I declared it outside the component (so it can be used anywhere in the file *after* the declaration). If you declare it within a function then its scope is limited to *that* function, so if you added it to `constructor` it is only valid there. Does this make sense?